# Android device unable to connect with BleGattServer

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am trying to run the following two Google Sample projects:

1) Sample BLE Gatt Server https://github.com/androidthings/sample-bluetooth-le-gattserver

2) Sample BLE Gatt Client https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt

I am using 2 phones:

1) **Samsung Galaxy S5**

2) **Motorola G4 Plus**

After adding small snippets of code for providing BLE and Coarse Location Access permissions, the projects worked with the Samsung Galaxy S5 hosting the server i.e. github project 1 and the Moto G4 Plus running the BLE Gatt client.

However, on reversing the roles, that is `Samsung Galaxy S5` running the client and the `Moto G4 Plus` hosting the server, I am not able to achieve successful connection.

I tried running the client on another phone (a Moto G5) and that failed too.

It seems the `Moto G4 Plus` is not able to connect successfully.

Can anyone please suggest why this could be happening? Are there any special permissions I need to take care of?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
After attempting to debug the app, I found that on the problematic device i.e. the Moto G4 Plus, after connectGatt is called, BluetoothGattCallback is called but onConnectionStateChange() is not called.

Answer (score 0):

It seems restarting the phone solves this issue.

As I had reported earlier, the Moto G4 Plus was generating a BluetoothGattCallback but wasn't really executing function within the callback. I spent about a week trying to understand if this was either a hardware limitation or a permission issue. I had even cycled the the Bluetooth on and off several times. Apparently, powering down the phone and restarting solved all issues. This might be useful for someone who might face the same problem.